# is there a way to align icon with text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building my first flutter app and I'm faced with a problem I'm trying to create a container that will allow you to choose several cities. I cannot align the text and the icon

```
child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
            height: 40,
            width: 700,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 0.5, color: Colors.brown),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'SÉLECTIONNEZ UNE VILLE',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: can you add some kind of visual to better explain your problem and goal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `crossAxisAlignment` and `mainAxisAlignment` property of the `Row` widgets to determine how the children of the `Row` widget will be placed.

> To center the `Text` and `Icon` vertically in the `Row` widget, set `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center`.

> To center the `Text` and `Icon` horizontally in the `Row` widget, set `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center`.

I added a demo code using your widget tree as an example, I also removed the `top padding` you gave the `Container` as it was putting the items downwards.

```
Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                  height: 40,
                  width: 700,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 0.5, color: Colors.brown),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                  child: Row(
                    // set the crossaxisalignment so the [items] in the  will be vertically centered
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    // set the crossaxisalignment so the [items] will be horizontally centered
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'SÉLECTIONNEZ UNE VILLE',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `MainAxisAlignment` and `Expanded` Property inside `Row`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
        height: 40,
        width: 700,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 0.5, color: Colors.brown),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Text('SÉLECTIONNEZ UNE VILLE',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ),
              Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,size: 30),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your top padding was messing the alignment.Try the following:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 0.5, color: Colors.brown),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            'SÉLECTIONNEZ UNE VILLE',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 14,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 10),
          Icon(
            Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
            size: 30,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```